# Is there any way to convert a .db file to a .accdb file

Tags: database, sqlite

For an assignment we are required to create a database in Microsoft Access but would much rather create it in python with Sqlite3. Is there anyway I could convert a .db file (the file that sqlite uses) to a .accdb (the file that microsoft access uses)? Thanks.

Comment: You are required to use Access, so you're going to lose marks if you use Python instead. If you insist, [this seems to be one way](https://sqliteviewer.com/blog/export-sqlite-to-access/).

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks! This works a treat. and I'll only lose marks if the teacher finds out :))